# Flutter - RawAutocomplete - How to use textEditingController without fieldViewBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, flutter-textformfield

How to use `textEditingController` without `fieldViewBuilder`?
I found something like this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawAutocomplete/textEditingController.html

But how to take out `TextFormField` from appBar and move it to body?

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get autoComplete behavior ? You can just cut and paste the textFiled on body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just cut and paste the `TextFormField` on body

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(...),
          RawAutocomplete<String>(..),
           
    );
  }
```

You can also check

- [`SearchDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) & sample [example](https://github.com/yeasin50/routine_helper/blob/master/lib/features/routine/widgets/search_delegate.dart)
- [simple_autocomplete_formfield](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/flutter/others/autoTextFieldComplete.dart) and  [example](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/flutter/others/autoTextFieldComplete.dart)
- [more on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=auto%20complete)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Yeasing. I thought that `RawAutocomplete` is not working then with `TextFormField`because its not integrated